# Producing the figure of a tensor in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a scientific document, where a section deals with tensors.

I spent some time with TikZ trying to replicate the image below, without success. From what I noticed, any rotation I attempted with a a base "square" came out distorted. I may have failed to understand how TikZ handles perspectives but without even being able to make the top and bottom rotate properly, I gave up.

Any LaTeX/TikZ guru here that would be willing to show me how it's done?

[image: Text]

Comment: Hello! Please provide the code you have written so far, so that others have something to work with.

Comment: The built-in projections by Ti*k*Z are not orthographic. Either load the `tpp` library or the `tikz-3dplot` package. Then it is straightforward to draw this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{150}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,line join=round,
    thick,>=Stealth,pics/dreibein/.style={code={%
      \foreach \XX [count=\YY from 0] in {#1}
      {
      \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- ($\XX1*(\dreibein\YY)$)
        node[above,dreibein/label]{$\sigma_{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dreibein/d}
        \the\numexpr\YY+1}$};}
    }},dreibein/.cd,label/.style={},d/.initial={}]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (4,0,0) node[above]{$x_1$};
 \draw[->]  (O) -- (0,6,0) node[above]{$x_2$};
 \draw[->]  (O) -- (0,0,6) node[left]{$x_3$};
 \def\dreibein#1{\ifcase#1
 {1,0,0}\or{0,1,0}\or{0,0,1}\fi}
 \def\lstcols{"red","yellow","orange"}
 \begin{scope}[shift={(0,4,4)}]
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(Mod(\X+1,3))},
    evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(Mod(\X+2,3))}]in {0,1,2}
  {\path ($-2*(\dreibein\X)$) pic[dreibein/label/.style={opacity=0}]{dreibein={-,-,-}};
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\lstcols}[\X]}
   \draw[fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.2] ($-2*(\dreibein\X)+2*(\dreibein\Y)+2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($-2*(\dreibein\X)+2*(\dreibein\Y)-2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($-2*(\dreibein\X)-2*(\dreibein\Y)-2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($-2*(\dreibein\X)-2*(\dreibein\Y)+2*(\dreibein\Z)$) -- cycle;
   }
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(Mod(\X+1,3))},
    evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(Mod(\X+2,3))}]in {0,1,2}
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\lstcols}[\X]}
    \draw[fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.4] ($2*(\dreibein\X)+2*(\dreibein\Y)+2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($2*(\dreibein\X)+2*(\dreibein\Y)-2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($2*(\dreibein\X)-2*(\dreibein\Y)-2*(\dreibein\Z)$)
    -- ($2*(\dreibein\X)-2*(\dreibein\Y)+2*(\dreibein\Z)$) -- cycle;
   \path ($2*(\dreibein\X)$) pic[dreibein/d=\the\numexpr\X+1]{dreibein={+,+,+}};
   }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, there was no way I could have achieved the desired result from the beginning without additional support packages.
This is an amazing reproduction of the concept and I'll definitely be able to go on from here. Thank you!